# How i can Binding parent ItemControl inside another ItemControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm using Wpf with MVVM pattern, so in Xamel i have an itemControl holds another itemcontrol each itemcontrol binding from different ObservableCollection, the result it supposed to be like grouping each data holds punch of data(Categories and subcategories), so i'm binding the usercontrole from my viewmodel and so on here is my viewModel code

```
public class BudgetViewModel:ViewModelBase,IBudgetViewModel
    {
          public BudgetViewModel(IBudgetLookupsDataService BudgetLookupsDataService)
           {
                  CategoryBudgets = new ObservableCollection<CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel>();
                  SubCategoryBudgets = new ObservableCollection<SubCategoryBudgetItemsViewModel>();
           }
         public async Task LoadBudgetCategories()
         {
          var categories = await _budgetLookupsDataService.GetBugetCategory();
        
            CategoryBudgets.Clear();
           if(categories.Count()!=0)
             {
             foreach (var cat in categories)
               {
                var subcategory = await _budgetLookupsDataService
                       .GetBudgetSubCategoriesPerMounth(DateforSearch, cat.IdCategory);
                CategoryBudgets.Add(new CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel(cat.IdCategory, 
                                    cat.CategoryName));
                foreach (var sub in subcategory)
                {
                   
                    SubCategoryBudgets.Add(new SubCategoryBudgetItemsViewModel(sub.IdSubCategory, 
                                         sub.SubCategoryName, sub.BudgetId, sub.BudgetPerMonth));
                }
               
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

and here is the class inside the observable

```
public class CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
   public CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel(int categoryId,string categoryName)
       {
               CategoriesId = categoryId;
               CategoriesName = categoryName;
       }
     public int CategoriesId { get; set; }
  
    public string CategoriesName
    {
        get { return _categoriesName; }
        set 
        { 
            
            _categoriesName = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
            
        }
    }
}
```

and the next class of next observable

```
 public class SubCategoryBudgetItemsViewModel: ViewModelBase
 {
    public SubCategoryBudgetItemsViewModel(int subcategoryId, string subcategoryname,
        int? idBudget, decimal budgetAmount)
         {
               SubCategoryId = subcategoryId;
               SubCategoryName = subcategoryname;
                BudgetId = idBudget;
              BudgetAmount = budgetAmount;
          }
              public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? BudgetId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName
    {
        get { return _subcategoryname; }
        set { _subcategoryname = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public decimal BudgetAmount
    {
        get { return _budgetamount; }
        set
        {
            _budgetamount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }
   }
```

and my Xamel Code :

```
       <ItemsControl x:Name="Item"  ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryBudgets}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="GrdData" >
                                    <Expander Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                   Header="{Binding CategoriesName}" Cursor="Hand" IsExpanded="True">
                                        <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategoryBudgets}" >
                                             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                      <DataTemplate>
                                                                                                                                           
                                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubCategoryId}"/>

                                                      </DataTemplate>
                                              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                      </ItemsControl>
                                   </Expander>
                                </Grid>
                             </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      </ItemsControl>
```

When i run the Expander render and the binding work fine but another itemcontrol it doesn't work at all
So my question is why the inner itemcontrol doesn't work and thanks for all

Comment: Are you getting any log in output window. I believe to have binding work you need to have the right data context; check with this --- `<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName="Item" DataContext.SubCategoryBudgets}" >`.

Comment: @user1672994 I tried it this now but still doesn't work :(

Comment: It should work, provided that SubCategoryBudgets is a public property like CategoryBudgets. We can't know. The correct expression would be `ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Item, Path=DataContext.SubCategoryBudgets}"`. It is however unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. All category items would show the same collection of sub-categories.

Comment: @Clemens I did't know why didn't work I tried ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Item, Path=DataContext.SubCategoryBudgets}" syntax and i populate the SubCategoryBudgets inside  CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel doesn't work and i tried populate  the SubCategoryBudgets inside veiwmodel it didn't work too, in two ways the SubCategoryBudgets has data but didn't render in itemcontrol i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finlay the child itemcontrol works well like the parent :), i made small changes, here is the chnges in CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel

```
public class CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
public CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel(int categoryId, string categoryName)
{
    CategoriesId = categoryId;
    CategoriesName = categoryName;
   SubCategoryBudgets = new ObservableCollection<SubCategoryBudgetItemsViewModel>();
}
public int CategoriesId { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<SubCategoryBudgetItemsViewModel> SubCategoryBudgets { get; set; }

public string CategoriesName
{
    get { return _categoriesName; }
    set
    {

        _categoriesName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();

     }
  }
}
```

and i populate the SubCategoryBudgets here in CategoryBudgetItemsViewModel. and here is the Xamel Code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Item"  ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryBudgets}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="GrdData" >
                                <Expander Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                               Header="{Binding CategoriesName}" Cursor="Hand" IsExpanded="True">
                                    <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubCategoryBudgets}"
                                         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                  <DataTemplate>
                                                                                                                                       
                                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SubCategoryId}/>

                                                  </DataTemplate>
                                          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                  </ItemsControl>
                               </Expander>
                            </Grid>
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl>
```

Thank you @Clemens,@user1672994 and @icode for your effort to help me,
Thanks for all of you Guys